# Placing an existing function's arguments in a call to another function in an LLVM Function Pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing an LLVM function pass. I have a function `foo(int a, int b)`, where in some instances, I'll need to replace it's call with `bar(int a, int b)`.

The way I wanted to do it is to basically:

- Locate the `foo()` I need to replace
- Make a `CallInst` to `bar()`
- Populate `CallInst::Create` with the arguments of `foo()`
- Make a call to `ReplaceInstWithInst()` to have it work

Everything is working just fine, but the arguments of `foo()` are not getting copied to `bar()`. When the replacement call is executed, the arguments of `bar()` are just null.

Here's the relevant code:

```c
bool runOnFunction(Function& F) override
{
    CallInst* call_to_foo = 0;
    Function* foo_func = 0;

    /*
    Loop over all calls in the function and populate foo_func when you find it.

    If we reached below, that means the current function we're in has a call to
    foo() (inside call_to_foo) that we need to replace with bar(). Also, foo_func
    is pointing to a foo Function
    */

    Function* bar_func = get_bar_func();

    // Collect foo args
    // I believe here is the issue: the arguments are not copied
    //  properly or there must be a deep-copy of sorts for it to work
    std::vector<Value*> bar_func_args;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < foo_func->arg_size(); i++) {
        Argument* arg = foo_func->arg_begin() + i;
        bar_func_args.push_back(arg);
    }

    auto* inst_to_replace = CallInst::Create(
        bar_func, ArrayRef<Value*>(bar_func_args),
        "bar_func");

    ReplaceInstWithInst(
    call_inst->getParent()->getInstList(),
    BBI, inst_to_replace);

    return true;
}
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Populate the new call instruction with the arguments from the old call instruction, not from the function being called.

Comment: Ah right!!! How would one get the arguments of a CallInst?

Comment: [getArgOperand()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ab2caa29167597390ab2fc3cf30d70389)

Comment: Many thanks! Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you want are in the call instruction, not in the function being called, so you ned to populate the new call using the [operands from the previous cal instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ab2caa29167597390ab2fc3cf30d70389).